# Getting unknown column error in jdbc java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
   PreparedStatement predstaveFilmaStavek = con.prepareStatement("select shows_id from shows where movies_movie_id=?");
    predstaveFilmaStavek.setInt(1, bazniIDfilma);
    ResultSet predstaveFilma = predstaveFilmaStavek.executeQuery();
    ArrayList<Show> predstave = new ArrayList<Show>();
    while (predstaveFilma.next()) {
        predstave.add(new ShowDao().selectShow(predstaveFilma.getInt(1)));
    }
```

this is giving me following error:

```
un. 03, 2017 1:06:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/kino] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /filmXML.jsp at line 17

14:     ResultSet predstaveFilma = predstaveFilmaStavek.executeQuery();
15:     ArrayList<Show> predstave = new ArrayList<Show>();
16:     while (predstaveFilma.next()) {
17:         predstave.add(new ShowDao().selectShow(predstaveFilma.getInt(1)));
18:     }
19: %>
20: 


Stacktrace:] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

I have the column `movies_movie_id` in the database... so what gives?

I have to type more words here so my question gets edited...-.-

MySQL that creates the table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE shows 
(
    `shows_id` INT auto_increment,
    `show_id` VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
    `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
    `city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `center` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `theater` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `movies_movie_id` int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`shows_id`)
);
  
ALTER TABLE shows
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_shows_movies FOREIGN KEY
(`movies_movie_id`) REFERENCES movies(`movies_id`);
```

Comment: Can you provide the table schema?

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual query/code which generated this error?

Comment: clean recompile and redeploy the project, the error is about "id" not "movies_movie_id"

Comment: `movies_movie_id`  is that the correct column name ? Also I get errors when there are no spaces. Use `movies_movie_id = ?`

Comment: cleaning/rebuilding gives same result. i have now pasted the mysql create table statement.

Comment: could you update selectShow() method here?

Comment: Not possible: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c88a6/2/0 Where does the "id" come from? The driver didn't invent that name "id"

Comment: You need to show more code, and the entire stacktrace, because the exception indicates line 17 is the problem, and that likely means the problem is with whatever `ShowDao` does, not the code shown. So: post the entire stacktrace, and post the code of `ShowDao.selectShow`.